# Update documents without loop in MongoDB with Golang

Tags: mongodb, algorithm, go

I have a collector module that pulls a remote API every 30 seconds.
That gives me a list of objects that I insert or update in a MongoDB database.

```
{
   "id" : "oulkhhvoiupokb",
   "name" : "test1",
   "status" : "OPEN"
},
{
   "id" : "oulkhhvoisksbsjkkb",
   "name" : "test2",
   "status" : "CLOSED"
}
```

In fact, I only collect the objects that have the OPEN status. And with a loop, I set the rest of the object as CLOSED (because they are not OPEN).
But in the future, it will take a lot of time because the amont of object will grow.

I work with Golang and MGO package.

Is there a way to do it faster and cleaner please ? Something like setting a basic field value for Mongo documents ?

To explain it differently, when I will insert the OPEN objects in the database, all the other ones that are already in database must be CLOSED. Can Mongo do it ?

Thanks.

Comment: What is it you want to do exactly? Change status to `"CLOSED"` of all documents where it is not `"OPEN"` (and not already `"CLOSED"` of course)?

Comment: See ["multi"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#multi-parameter) in the options to `.update()`. Same thing applies to every language implemented driver. Probably a bit better than "strings" is to use [`$bit`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/bit/) with `xor` if there is only one item meant to be "turned on". Using `$bit` you can do one update statement then rather than two. But the value needs to be "numeric" instead.

Comment: Thanks for help. From the remote API, I only pull the objects that are OPEN because it is the information I need to have very quickly. That being collected, I know that all the documents in my database that are not in the list of object that I got from the remote API are closed, because they are not in the list of OPEN. So I perform a loop to `.update()` them as CLOSED. My need is to do not perform the loop and set to CLOSED all the object that are not in the list of OPEN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to use `func (c *Collection) UpdateAll(selector interface{}, update interface{}) (info *ChangeInfo, err error)` with the `$nin` for the selector and `$set` for the update.